# How can I move many files without having Argument list too long?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xargs, mv

I am trying to move about 700,000 .jpg files from one directory to another in my Ubuntu server. I tried the following:

```
xargs mv *  -t /var/www/html/
```

and

```
echo (*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) | xargs mv -t /var/www/html/
```

and

```
echo (*.jpg) | xargs mv -t /var/www/html/
```

and

```
find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs mv * ../
```

and they all give me the same error: /usr/bin/xargs: Argument list too long

what should I do? Please help me out. Thanks :)

Comment: Related: [Does "argument list too long"
 restriction apply to shell builtins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47443380/does-argument-list-too-long-restriction-apply-to-shell-builtins)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use `find` I would recommend you to use the `-exec` attribute. So your result should be `find . -name "*.jpg" -exec mv {} /home/new/location \;`.

However I would recommend to check what the `find` command returns you, replacing the `exec` part with: `-exec ls -lrt {} \;`

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
find /path/to/old-directory -type f | xargs -i mv "{}" /path/to/new-directory
```

Answer (score 2):

You could have tried:

```
 for f in *.jpg do;
   mv -tv $f /var/www/html/
 done
 for f in *.png do;
   mv -tv $f /var/www/html/
 done
 for f in *.bmp do;
   mv -tv $f /var/www/html/
 done
```

also, you should carefully read [xargs(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html); I strongly suspect that

```
 find . -name "*.jpg" -print0 | xargs -n 1000 -I '{}' mv '{}'  ../
```

should work for you

At last, learn more about [rename(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html). It is probably enough for the job.

Comment: On raspberry pi I have played with this command and it started working when semicolon was moved before 'do' keyword so command looked like this:
"for f in *.jpg; do mv -f $f /var/www/html/jpgs/; done"